# Creating Arrays Dynamically with a for loop

Tags: javascript

I am making an application that needs to read 10 song names and 5 ratings per song. I thing that having one array for each song that will store the name and the 5 different ratings would be ideal but I don't know how to dynamically create arrays with a for loop. Any ideas? Here is a sample:

```
for (var song = 1; song < 11; song++) {
    prompt("Give song title, No:" + " " + song);
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        prompt("Give song No:" + " " + song + " " + ", rating:" + i);   
    }  
}
```

Comment: @Alex, why in the world would you need jQuery for a for loop and array?

Comment: The most likely data structure is a single array, with one element per song. Each song element would be an object with properties `name` and `ratings`, where `ratings` is a five-element array. You can create that array by, well, just creating it, then pushing new elements onto it each time through the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you have an array of objects, where each object contains a title and an array of ratings, giving you a structure that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    title: "First song",
    ratings: [ 5, 3, 4, 1, 4 ]
  },
  {
    title: "Second song",
    ratings: [ 2, 3, 2, 1, 1 ]
  }
]
```

Create the array first, then create an object for each song with an empty array for ratings. Then you can put the ratings in that array:

```
var songs = [];
for (var song = 0; song < 10; song++) {
  var title = prompt("Give song title, No: " + song);
  songs[song] = {
    title: title,
    ratings: []
  };
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var rating = prompt("Give song No: " + song + " , rating:" + i);
    songs[song].ratings.push(rating);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, one more question. How can for example alert the first rating of the second song.

Comment: @Theof: The second song is `songs[1]` and the ratings for that song is `songs[1].ratings` so that would be `alert(songs[1].ratings[0]);`.